# Detectar se URL é um encurtador de URL

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um input de texto em um formulário HTML onde o usuário do sistema insere um link. Esse link é copiado da URL. Preciso que seja aceito qualquer tipo de link, menos aquelas URLs 'encurtadas', tipo "goo.gl.". Como posso criar uma função para validar e verificar isso? É possível?

Comment: Você tem uma lista das url's encurtadas que não irá aceitar? Se não, o primeiro passo é listar todas que você encontrar para que possa criar uma expressão regular eficiente.

Comment: Você também pode criar uma regra: "domínio com no mínimo x caracteres" que sejam no formato  "domínio/chave" = bloqueio. Você pode procurar outros critérios, observando os encurtadores que existem, para evitar "falso positivo" e ter uma validação gerencia e eficiente.

Comment: Outro jeito é mandar uma requisição pra a URL postada, caso seja redirecionado, você poderá obter a URL real, ou bloquear, por não ser um link direto.

Comment: Concordo com as respostas do @user5978 . O grande problema é que talvez o próprio site que o usuário poste o link faça um redirecionamento. Nesse caso poderia ser verificado se o redirecionamento foi feito para o mesmo domínio, mas ainda assim seria arriscado. Digamos que eu inserisse a url: http://foo.com/bar que redirecione os usuários da Europa para http://foo.com.eu/bar, o sistema iria bloquear esse tipo de url, e esse é um tipo de redirecionamento que até mesmo o google faz para lidar com o acesso de usuários de diferentes países

Comment: É, se optar por uma solução genéricas, o sistema vai ter que ter uma certa "inelegância" para lidar com falso positivo. Esse é o "preço" para não ter que atualizar constantemente a lista de encurtadores, hehe.

Comment: Este site sabe dizer se é, ou não uma URL "encurtada". http://www.checkshorturl.com/expand.php. Não se trata de uma API, mas teu script pode submeter a URL, e analisar o retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma sugestão é fazer uma requisição na URL. Se detectar redirecionamento, pode ser um "encurtador", mas também pode não ser e estaria então impedindo URLs legítimas.

A partir desse ponto, compare com a quantidade de caracteres. Se for menor que X aumenta a probabilidade de ser um encurtador e descarta URLs maiores que fazem redirecionamento, mas não são encurtadores.

Parece bom até aqui, mas na prática, não funciona.

Vamos a um exemplo real:

**tinyurl.com** <- é um encurtador de URL
**globo.com** <- é menor que o tinyurl.com mas não é um encurtador.
**r7.com** <- é menor ainda..

Portanto a lógica em comparar o tamanho da URL ou do domínio, não é válida.

Talvez deva se perguntar, qual o objetivo em detectar se é um encurtador de URL?

Se for pelo fato de que redirecionam uma URL, então poderia apenas validar o redirect, independentemente de ser um encurtador ou não.

Comment: Como já foi comentado aqui, solução tem, mesmo que seja na força bruta, o que não é uma solução tão ruim, já que não existe um número extremamente alto de sites do tipo. Porem, uma solução genérica seria o melhor, mas há alguns problemas quanto aos critérios a ser utilizado, como você mesmo observou.

Comment: A quantidade de encurtadores é enorme. Por baixo, deve ter centenas de milhares. Dizer que fazer X ou Y é uma solução para algo que é inviável de fazer, é no mínimo conduzir ao erro. Um exemplo de  "erro" no proprio stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557116/regex-php-code-to-check-if-a-url-is-a-short-url

Comment: Isso prova que se não for "viável" é pelo menos bem possível implementar: http://www.checkshorturl.com/expand.php.

Comment: Note que são termos muito distintos. Dizer que "não é viável" não quer dizer "não é possível". Esse site que postou apenas expande urls que são redirecionadas. Não quer dizer que realmente "detecta" um encurtador de url... Se você provar aqui que é viável, eu mesmo darei um negativo no que eu postei.. rsrsr se for possível ..rsrs

Comment: Você esta dizendo que é impossível validar se uma URL é permitida, com base em uma lista de URLs? Sei não, acredito que diversas aplicações trabalham dessa forma. É como validar se um email já está cadastrado para um usuário, com base em uma lista de outros cadastros. A lista precisa ser extremamente grande, pra que isso torne a validação inviável, ainda assim, existe a possibilidade de utilizar índices. Enfim, o que torna isso uma solução não muito boa, é o trabalho de "caçar" encurtadores novos.

Comment: Mais uma vez, não disse em momento algum que é impossível. Apenas que é INVIÁVEL. Mais uma vez, o termo "inviável" é diferente de "impossível"..

Comment: Eu afirmei que o site prova que é possível, e não que você disse que é impossível :D. Quanto a questão de viabilidade, não vejo o que dificulta cadastrar uma lista de urls em uma base dados, e quando um usuário fornecer uma URL, fazer uma busca, para checar se ela está na "black list". Arrisco a dizer que muitos sites fazem coisa parecida.

Comment: Fontes para isso, existem várias: http://bit.do/list-of-url-shorteners.php https://www.techmaish.com/list-of-230-free-url-shorteners-services/ https://www.hashtags.org/platforms/twitter/list-of-url-shorteners/

Comment: Apenas para finalizar e deixar mais claro. É inviável criar uma lista de encurtadores pois não se sabe nem mesmo a quantidade existente. O mundo não se resume a sites dos EUA, Europa e Brasil. E mesmo nessas 3 regiões há dezenas, senão centenas de milhares de encurtadores e a cada dia surge 1 ou 20 novos.. Enfim, não há um padrão, não há um controle.. Nada.. -> inviável.

Comment: Essas listas dos links que vc passou é alguma piada? rsrsrs Como disse no comentário acima.. talvez exista centenas de milhares.. não são 20, 40, nem 200, 300 ... é coisa para mais de 100, 300 mil.. só no ocidente.

Comment: Meio exagerado esse número. Mas mesmo assim, em uma tabela indexada, funcionaria perfeitamente. Mas na real, somente serviços mais populares seriam necessários, Caso uma outra URL comece a aparecer frequentemente nos cadastros, basta adiciona-la também na lista. Como eu não faço ideia, qual é o contexto do problema, não tem como afirmar se eventuais "erros" seriam aceitáveis.

Comment: Concordo com o @DanielOmine. Criar uma tabela não é uma solução definitiva, mas não é descartada. Essa pode ser usada junto com uma outra. Exemplo: em Javascript possui uma pequena lista de encurtadores banidos, que impedirá que "usuários normais não publiquem", enquanto no server side a mesma lista pode existir, mas não é esse o foco. O server side pode requisitar o URL através de cURL. O Facebook faz isso, o Google faz isso. Dessa forma poderia verificar se o goo.gl/xxxxx fosse para meusite.com, ele obteria o ultimo `location` obtido. Além disso, buscaria por `http-equiv="refresh"` e etc.

Comment: PS: Esse método também impede que você crie o seu site pseudo-encurtador. Imagine que meusite.com esteja banido e não possa compartilhar. Então eu crio o goo.gl para ele, o goo.gl está na lista e já vai ser banido, poupando processamento. Se eu criar o meusite2.com, redirecionando para o meusite.com, também será impedido, porque o sistema não depende de lista.

Answer (score 2):

O que você pode fazer é inserir em um `array` ou `MySQL` (dependendo do tipo de linguagem que você irá usar) algumas das URL's que são encurtadas. Por exemplo **goo.gl**, **tinyurl.com**, etc.

Um código feito com PHP por exemplo:

```
    <?php
    $urls = array('goo.gl', 'tinyurl.com'); //Insere as URL's que são encurtadoras

    $url_input = trim(strtolower($_POST['url'])); //Pega a URL que o usuário informou

$filtra_url = parse_url($url_input);

$url = $filtra_url['host'];


    if(in_array($url, $urls)){
    echo 'Você informou uma URL encurtada. Não permitimos isso!';
    }else{
    echo 'URL autorizada';
    }
    ?>
```